# PHP deleting the second line in a file if the file is of a certain length

Tags: php, fwrite

When a user signs up for an account on my website their own page is created called USERNAME.php. 
Whenever the username "bob" gets signed in then a new line is added to bob.php which contains the time, date and ip address of that login.
 What I want to do is have a maximum of 20 lines in that file, so that the file doesn't get too big over time. 
I have the first line as "Login Retrieval for **bob**" and then the most recent login result at the bottom. So the first line should not be deleted, but the second line should be deleted with every login (only if the amount of lines is > 20). What would be the best way to go about doing this? Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain in detail the reason behind your decision to store data in a php file?
Anyway the ideal way should be to use a database, but if you prefer you could save your data as json in a text file too.

Comment: I was planning on saving it to a database, but then accidentally messed up my code. I then decided to experiment a bit and use the fwrite. All of the data is saved in the /usernames/ folder which I have password protected. I collect this data in case an account gets hacked. If the account holder reports the hack we can trace it to an ip with the gathered data, and suspend that ip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the `.php` extension is not used and that the file has up to twenty lines.

You could explode the file in lines using the `file()` function, `shift` out the first line to save it, then use `array_splice()` to extract the last 19, `unshift` the first line back into the new array to get up to 20 entries. `join` them and rewrite them back to the original file.

Better yet, write them onto a new file, then if everything went well, rename the new file onto the new.

```
    /**
     * @param $file    the input file
     * @param $n       total number of meaningful lines to keep (default 20)
     * @param $m       prefix lines to keep (default 1)
     *
     * @return         number of lines in case something was done
     *                 0 nothing to do
     *                 -1 file not found
     *                 -2 file not readable
     *                 -3 file not writeable
     *                 -4 write error
     *                 -8 bad parameter
     */

    function trim_file($file, $n = 20, $m = 1)
    {
            if (!file_exists($file))
                    return -1;
            if (!is_readable($file))
                    return -2;
            if (!is_writeable($file))
                    return -3;
            if ($m > $n)
                    return -8;
            $lines  = file($file);
            $num    = count($lines);

            // If file is short, no need to do anything
            if ($num <= $n)
                    return 0;

            $header = array_slice($lines, 0, $m);
            // Remove lines from 0 to ($num-($n-$m))
            // and replace them with the first $m lines
            array_splice($lines, 0, $num-($n-$m), $header);

            // Write file with new contents
            $fp = fopen($file . '.tmp', 'w');
            if (!$fp)
                    return -4;
            fwrite($fp, join('', $lines));
            fclose($fp);

            // Replace the file in one fell swoop.
            rename($file . '.tmp', $file);
            return count($lines);
    }
```

Comment: So you mean save all of the previous entries, excluding the second line (only if lines>20) and save all that data to bobtemp.php then assuming everything went well rename it to bob.php? Assuming thats what you meant, GREAT IDEA!!!

Comment: Also, could you post some code for this? That would be very helpful, but if not then thats ok.

Answer (score 0):

If there only 20 lines. Would be easy to read the file to an array and manipulate it that way. Could easily unset array elements and keep the total count to 20. Then write new info back to the file

Comment: I think that @Iserni is working on some code that he will be posting. Thank you though!